# i dont know what happening right now with my trigger PL/SQL script

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

fix this error pls

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BELITIKET 
AFTER INSERT ON PENUMPANG FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TIKET(NIK,NAMA_PENUMPANG, NAMA_KERETA,RUTE,HARGA)
  SELECT p.NIK, p.NAMA, k.NAMA_KERETA, p.RUTE, k.HARGA
  FROM PENUMPANG p, KERETA_API k
  WHERE p.RUTE = k.RUTE and p.WAKTU = k.WAKTU_KEBERANGKATAN;
END;
```

this is the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SCOTT.TRIGGER1' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Comment: The error message is on trigger "SCOTT.TRIGGER1". This is not the trigger you are showing us. Can you please show us the trigger that became invalid?

Comment: If you're logged in as SCOTT, the trigger owner, then you can query the `user_errors` view to see what the trigger compilation error is. As another user you *might* be able to see it in `all_errors` or `dba_errors`. (The trigger you've shown will get a run-time mutating table error, as Littlefoot explained; but you've shown the result of compilation error, apparently on a different trigger...)

Answer (score 2):

Mutating table error, I presume (it would be easier if you stated it yourself). You can't select from the same table that is just being updated. Use `:new` pseudorecord instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER belitiket
   AFTER INSERT
   ON penumpang
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tiket (nik,
                      nama_penumpang,
                      nama_kereta,
                      rute,
                      harga)
      SELECT :new.nik,
             :new.nama,
             k.nama_kereta,
             :new.rute,
             k.harga
        FROM kereta_api k
       WHERE     :new.rute = k.rute
             AND :new.waktu = k.waktu_keberangkatan;
END;
```